# How do I link my sitemap to Yahoo Boss?

Tags: search-engine, sitemap, yahoo-boss-api

Let's say a want to use Yahoo Boss for a brand new, unindexed site; Is there a way I submit an XML feed i.e. a site map in order to get results before The site gets indexed ?

Comment: He's probably too busy running Yahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to submit your site through [Yahoo Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/) ([additional help](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/siteexplorer/)). Then assuming that your site gets indexed, results should be available via the [Yahoo BOSS search webservice](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/).